# Debugging a qbo3 Statement

Tags: sql-server, qbo3

I have a qbo3 statement that causes an error. When I invoke the statement, I am routed to an error page that does not contain enough information to help me determine the root cause of the problem.

Does qbo3 contain any tools to assist in debugging the statement?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom statements](https://dev.azure.com/quandisopensource/Documentation/_wiki/wikis/Documentation.wiki/14/Module-Configuration?anchor=statements) created in qbo3 can be debugged from Templates > Reports > [Ad-Hoc Report](https://dev.azure.com/quandisopensource/Documentation/_wiki/wikis/Documentation.wiki/152/Ad-Hoc-Report).

You can use this tool to iteratively test and fix any statements you are designing.

In the screen shot below, the statement `Foreclosure/B2BDataStore` is set up for testing:

[image]

Note:

- The `Module` is `Foreclosure`
- The `Query` is `Basic`
- The `Base Statement` is `B2BDataStore`
- The `Payload` contains a query string for any parameters you wish to pass to the statement

In the `Results` panel, we can see errors reported by SQL server, including:

```sql
Msg 209, Level 16, Line 20
Ambiguous column name 'ProcessID'.
...
Msg 207, Level 16, Line 238
Invalid column name 'ProcessProcessTemplateID'.
```

To see the actual SQL being processed, check the `Debug Statement` checkbox. Instead of executing the statement's SQL, qbo3 will generate the SQL and display it in the Results panel.

In this particular case, the culprit is:

```sql
SELECT ...
  ProcessID,
  ...
FROM Bankruptcy
  INNER JOIN Process ON Process.ProcessID = Bankruptcy.ProcessID
WHERE Process.UpdatedDate >= @FromDate
```

Since both the `Bankruptcy` and `Process` table contain `ProcessID` column, the correct syntax would be to clarify which table's `ProcessID` to return:

```sql
SELECT ...
  Process.ProcessID,
  ...
FROM Bankruptcy
  INNER JOIN Process ON Process.ProcessID = Bankruptcy.ProcessID
WHERE Process.UpdatedDate >= @FromDate
```

The second error appears to simply be a typo:

```sql
ProcessProcessTemplateID
```

should be

```sql
Process.ProcessTemplateID
```